# Multi-step, live updating search

Tags: plugins, search

I'm creating a website and want to set up a multi-step (live) filter for searching companies, industries etc and now I'm starting to explain...

I have 3 categories. First category has 5 criterias. When you choose one of them (it should be possible to choose ONLY one in the first stage) there are more criterias on the first sub-category and when you choose one criteria from the first sub-category (also should be possible to choose ONLY one) there comes the second sub-category where you can choose more criterias. It would be the best if you get the results LIVE. I'm searching for days and still can't find anything. Hope it's understandable and someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need conditional form fields for selecting your criteria based on previous criteria selection, then for live filtering, you would use an ajax filter instead of the regular form submit. I assume you are filtering WordPress posts. If you search for "conditional form fields" and "wordpress ajax filter" you should find lots of results. I believe the plugin Advanced Custom Fields can help if you don't want to code the build your conditional form by hand. There are a number of tutorials online regarding using ajax filters for querying WordPress posts.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying now the "conditional form field" but actually i think i am too dumb to display it on the website. Any tipp? I tried it with elementor pro and with a shortcode. In both ways it doesn't show. :(